# How to instantiate an object complying with zod schema defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, zod

In my React project, I have integrated the zod library, like so:

```js
const schema = z.object({
  id: z.string().optional(),
  name: z.string().min(1, "Name is required"),
  country: z.string().min(1, "Country is required")
});

type Customer = z.infer<typeof schema>;
```

I am trying to instantiate an object of the type Customer.

In one of my components, I try to use the type in this manner:

I can't figure out what the right syntax would be for this:
`const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(new Customer());`

The error I get on that `new Customer()` syntax is: 'Customer' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.ts(2693)

I figured I could maybe declare a class of the Customer type, but that didn't work either.

Got any ideas, please?

Comment: This seems to have worked: `const [customer, setCustomer] = useState(schema.parse({}));`
I will confirm briefly

Comment: In typescript, objects can satisfy a type without having an explicit `class` definition. Something like `{ id: '11', name: 'steve', country: 'usa' }` should parse successfully. `id` is optional so `{ name: 'steve', country: 'usa' }` should also work